# Changing order of elements in rmarkdown HTML output

Tags: r

I built a rmarkdown code that connects to teradata that fetches required data into dataframes. Using these dataframe i am running proportion tests at the bottom of the code to get final output result. I am trying to push this final output result to top of the HTML output file. Below is a dummy code that is representative of my actual piece of code.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
Fetches data from Teradata into a dataframe called ABC
```

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
proprotion test on ABC. Results saved in a table called DEF.
```

print(DEF)
````

When I look at my HTML output file I have to scroll down to bottom of page to look at results. As of now I found a work around using explicit hyperlinks that will navigate to desired point in the output file.

Comment: there's no way you have two chunks named `setup`, but look up chunk referencing: https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/make-prettier-documents-by-reusing-chunks-in-rmarkdown/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ref.label` chunk option to call a chunk before it is actually evaluated. Here, the first chunk will print the result of the last chunk:

````
```{r lab2, ref.label="result"}

```

```{r setup}
# some setup code
```

```{r result, echo=FALSE, results='hide'}
1+1
```
````